# Is it possible to open a link only with a scheme?

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

For example, I have 2 applications to open in my own app. They have such `intent-filters`:

First app:

```xml
<intent-filter
    android:autoVerify="true">

    <action
        android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category
        android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:scheme="appscheme1"
        android:host="myapp1.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/" />

</intent-filter>
```

Second app:

```xml
<intent-filter
    android:autoVerify="true">

    <action
        android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category
        android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:scheme="appscheme2"
        android:pathPrefix="/" />

</intent-filter>
```

So as you can mention, the second application doesn't have the `host` parameter. So I can open the second app with such code, only using the `scheme`:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("appscheme2://"))
startActivity(intent)
```

But I'm unable to do so with the first one, I need to use host too:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("appscheme1://myapp1.com"))
startActivity(intent)
```

The code below doesn't work. I'm getting `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent`:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("appscheme1://"))
startActivity(intent)
```

Is it possible to use only the `scheme` parameter to open an application even if the `host` parameter is set for that `scheme`?
Exact thing I need: I need to check is an application installed knowing only it has some `scheme` registered. It might have the `host` parameter specified too, and might not, I won't know about that, I only know about `scheme`. Every application has it's unique `scheme`. Generally, I need code like this to work:

```
fun isAppInstalled(sheme: String, packageManager: PackageManager): Boolean {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("$sheme://"))
    return intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null
}
```

Comment: I see no intent filters.

Comment: @blackapps just updated the code blocks